# Copy csv to postgres table using python

Tags: python, python-3.x, postgresql

I have csv file with records , would like to select rows from csv and load it to postgres table

eg

| col1 | col2 | col3 | col4 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| abc | 123 | xyz | 13-Jul |
| def | 345 | tyr | 14-Jul |

I wanted to select records greater than specfied date from csv for eg date>sysdate and load to tbale in below format

| col1 | col2 | Jscol3 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| abc | 123 | {col3:'xyz',col4:'13-Jul'} |
| def | 345 | {col3:'tyr ',col4:'14-Jul'} |

i am aware how to read and write to table, but want advise on filtering csv rows and creating a json structure based on csv columns and load to col3 in table

```
import psycopg2 #import the postgres library

 #connect to the database
 conn = psycopg2.connect(host='localhost',
                   dbname='database1',
                   user='postgres',
                   password='****',
                   port='****')  

cur = conn.cursor()

 with open('******.csv', 'r') as f:
next(f) # Skip the header row.
#f , <database name>, Comma-Seperated
cur.copy_from(f, '****', sep=',')
#Commit Changes
conn.commit()
#Close connection
conn.close()


f.close()
```

Comment: Why? You like duplicating data?

Comment: i just added an example...basically ill be loading few column to column in tbale ..rest other columns will be loaded as json structure

Comment: Again why?  You are just duplicating the data. Why not split it into separate rows?

Comment: i edited the table structure,can you check...theres no dupes...i wanted to generate a json structure for some othe columns in csv  and load it to a column table

Comment: Why are you storing JSON in Postgres?  Postgres is a relational database.  You should have individual columns with your data, so you can search for it.

Comment: @TimRoberts well, Postgres *does* support JSON natively. So you can query a JSON column based on the JSON itself.

Comment: can i not store it as clob object like in oracle...is it not allowed in postgres?

Comment: how can i create json structure from the csv columns and just add it to a clob column or text column in table.

Comment: we dont want too many columns in target table..so tryin to do a json structure to a table

Comment: It is more efficient to have many columns, to allow pgsql to index them.  If your data is JSON focused, perhaps Mongo would be a better choice.

Comment: We want it to be in the same structure...is it possible to do it by python script read through a csb and create a Json structure...pls let me know...I understand concerns reg postures etc...but I am just  looking for solution to create Json structure out of the some columns in a row in csv and load it to a target column